# Sublime Text break line at cursor

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor, line-breaks

I am using Sublime Text 3 with Vintage enabled. I have it set up so I can join lines using <kbd>shift+j</kbd> in command mode. I want to use <kbd>shift+k</kbd> to break a line at the cursor. Is this possible?

For example, if I have an array like the following:

`array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');`

I want to be able to move the cursor to each starting single quote, hit <kbd>shift+k</kbd> and have it move to another line. If I hit <kbd>shift+k</kbd> at the first quote, I would get this:

```
array(

    'item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with sublime+vintage mode, but can you make normal mode mappings? Then `nnoremap K i<cr><esc>` should work.

Comment: It doesn't look like that is possible with Sublime. At least not with the Vintage package. Not sure if another package could allow that or not.

Comment: Check out the [`Vintageous`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vintageous) package. I don't use it that often, but I've found that it has more key bindings and flexibility than the built-in `Vintage` mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in Vintage by setting a key binding such as the following in your user key bindings:

```json
{ "keys": ["K"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode"},
    ]
},
```

Note however that this will mask the following default key binding in Vintage, which may or may not be a problem:

```json
{ "keys": ["k"], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "move",
    "motion_args": {"by": "stops", "line_begin": true, "forward": false, "extend": true },
    "linewise": true },
    "context":
    [
        {"key": "setting.command_mode"},
        {"key": "vi_motion_mode", "operand": "line"}
    ]
},
```